# Debug web application in Eclipse under Oracle Application Server

Tags: java, eclipse, oc4j, oas

I am using Eclipse and I am familiar with Apache Tomcat.

I can run/debug my web applications under Tomcat.
But I can not do it for Oracle Application Server.

When I try to start the server from eclipse it is beginning to start, but after 240 seconds it says that timeout is reached.

Please suggest any method to debug under Oracle Application Server in Eclipse.

Comment: See if remote debugging is fine for you
http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/how-debug-remote-java-applicat

Answer (score 1):

@user179437: you can try following things:-

1. You can increase debug timeout setting in eclipse
2. you can increase heap memory size by passing java parameters in debug configuration
3. If it is windows machine, you can do netstat -a to check what is status of debug port on the machine where OAS is running. What happens to status of port when timeout happens.
4. Just check java home configured in  your eclipse and check its filesystem directory, if you are seeing any java heap dump files. If these files are created,  you may see useful error information in same.
5. Last but not least, I was having same issue in websphere 6.0 with myeclipse, then I needed to apply server latest patches which basically upgraded my JRE which resolved the issue.

Please let me know if you want to know detailed explanation on any of the steps above.

Answer (score 0):

Double-click on the server, and change the Start timeout in the Timeouts section.

Comment: Timeout value is very big. Problem is not in the timeout, the server does not start in anyway (from eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs:
- in Eclipse workspace under .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core
or
- in the deployment directory

There must be an error or something other useful message.